# Call executable .exe in C

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp, run

I would like to improve my Mathematica code by executing some function in C, since it is way faster. The flow would be:

- Mathematica: generate inputs and store in .dat file, then call .exe previously built in C
- exe: reads input and stores output in .dat
- Mathematica: reads output and so on

When I use `RunProcess`, apparently the file is executed correctly, however there is no output to be read by the end. How can I solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: It is discouraged on StackExchange to delete the question (which already had some comments) and post a new one with the exact same problem. As for your problem, try providing the directory: ``RunProcess[{NotebookDirectory[] <> "main.exe"}, ProcessDirectory -> NotebookDirectory[]]``.

Comment: Unfortunately you have not provided nearly enough detail for anyone to even guess at what might be happening. We don't know what your program does, we don't know what you write to which file, we don't know how you read the file back, ...

Comment: You can compile Mathematica code to C, with some limitations.  Maybe look into it.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few potential issues that could be causing the problem you're experiencing. Here are some things you could try:

1. Make sure that the .exe file you're calling is actually generating
   the output you expect. You can do this by running the .exe file from
   the command line and checking the output.
2. Make sure that the .dat file you're using for input and output is
   being written to and read from correctly. You can do this by
   manually inspecting the contents of the .dat file before and after
   the .exe file is run.
3. Make sure that the .dat file is in the correct location when the
   .exe file is run. If the .exe file is not able to find the .dat
   file, it won't be able to read from or write to it.
4. Make sure that the .exe file is being run with the correct
   arguments. If the .exe file is expecting certain arguments and they
   are not being passed correctly, it may not be able to generate the
   expected output.
5. If you are using the RunProcess function to call the .exe file, make
   sure that you are correctly specifying the input and output streams.
   The RunProcess function has options for specifying the input and
   output streams, and if these are not set correctly, the .exe file
   may not be able to read from or write to the .dat file.

Here is some sample code that demonstrates how you could use Mathematica's RunProcess function to execute an .exe file and read the output from a .dat file:

```
(* Generate input data and write to .dat file *)
inputData = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
Export["input.dat", inputData, "Table"];

(* Call .exe file and specify input and output streams *)
runProcess = RunProcess[{"path/to/exe/file", "arg1", "arg2"},  <|"StandardInput" -> "input.dat", "StandardOutput" -> "output.dat"|>];

(* Wait for .exe to finish running *)
WaitForProcess[runProcess];

(* Read output from .dat file *)
outputData = Import["output.dat", "Table"];

(* Print output data *)
Print[outputData];
```

This code first generates some input data and writes it to a .dat file using the Export function. It then calls the .exe file using the RunProcess function, specifying the input and output streams using the "StandardInput" and "StandardOutput" options. The code then waits for the .exe file to finish running using the WaitForProcess function, and finally reads the output from the .dat file using the Import function.